# Spark on hive replacing presto

Tags: apache-spark, hive, presto, hive-metastore

CONTEXT -
Integration of Hive metastore with any data analytics platform say, Presto, Spark etc
Assuming that the BI Tool is integrated to the Query Engine (Presto/Spark in this scenario), all the information regarding the tables/views will be displayed in BI Tool Dashboard.
However, the information (columns and respective datatypes) about the tables or Views can be found stored in metastore DB in the form of tables.

CASE SCENARIO:
Let us assume that we have initially connected Presto engine with Hive as metastore and we create some Views. Now, we should be able to find the views and their columns stored in hive.
Now, let us assume that we want to replace Presto with Spark and retain same metastore as before which has Views in it.
NOTE : Since, views are not materialised, the underlying datasource shall not contain any physical data pertaining to those views.

QUESTION:
How does Spark be aware of views and their respective 'Create' script in order to execute any queries related to that.